# How to write a Greater-than sign inside a jsx tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

im trying to print a Greater-than sign '<' inside of a button from material-ui with react but im getting a parsing error, there is some way to print that without a large code.

```
<Button onClick={includeOperator('eq')}> = </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('neq')}> != </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('gt')}> > </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('lt')}> < </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('gte')}> >= </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('lte')}> <= </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('between')}> between </Button>
```

[image: Parsing Error]

Comment: you can use it this way `{'<'}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it with following. It should work fine.

```
<Button onClick={includeOperator('eq')}> = </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('neq')}> != </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('gt')}> > </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('lt')}> {"<"} </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('gte')}> >= </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('lte')}> {"<="} </Button>
<Button onClick={includeOperator('between')}> between </Button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cookies-t9bln

Answer (score 2):

You can use html entities where you can write many special characters including the ones which are not on your keyboard.

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref